# Finding and printing the last word of a string with a space or tab delimiter

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, gcc

I'm trying to get the last word of a string as an `argv` parameter in C. How can I find the last word and delimit the strings that contain a space/tabs?

The definition of a word is *"a section of string delimited by spaces/tabs or by the start/end of the string."* I initially made a function to identify it is whitespace or tab; however, the solution I have does not for all cases. Most of it works, but when my `argv` has a string like `"asdkBakjsdhf1785    "`, the expected output should be `"asdkBakjsdhf1785"`, not `"asdkBakjsdhf1785    "`. All of these functions has to made from scratch and I'm only allowed to use the `write` function from the `<unistd.h>` library.

```
int my_isspace(char c)
{
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\t')
        return (1);
    return (0);
}

void    my_putstr(char *str)
{
    while (*str)
        write(1, str++, 1);
}

void    last_word(char *str)
{
    char *last;
    int i;

    i = 0;
    last = &str[i];
    while (str[i])
    {
        if (my_isspace(str[i]))
        {
            if (str[i + 1] >= '!' && str[i + 1] <= '~')
                last = &str[i + 1];
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (last)
        my_putstr(last);
}

int     main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2)
       last_word(argv[1]);
    my_putstr("\n");
    return (0);
}
```

For now, what it does is that it parses through the string and checks if it has a whitespace/tab. If it has, it will ignore it and move to the next character until it hits a character between `!` and `~` (including those). Once it hits to any of the characters in between, it will store the parsing into another empty string pointer to preserve what was the "last word". With the way that I'm using, where can I improve the tiny bit to delimit my space/tab at the end?

Comment: But let's say you do `" lorem,ipsum  "`, I'm getting `"lorem,ipsum "` instead of `"lorem,ipsum"`

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems. First it would help to make your `my_isspace()` roughly equivalent to `isspace()` so that it correctly considers line-ends as whitespace as well, e.g.

```
int my_isspace (const char c)
{
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n' || c == '\r')
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Next, you can make `last_word()` (and many other similar classification functions) much simpler by taking a *State Loop* approach and keeping a simple flag to help you with your classification. For instance here, it helps to know whether you are reading within a word or not. That lends itself to a simple in/out state, which you can track with a simple flag of `int in = 0;` for outside a word, and `in = 1;` when within a word.

Putting that in use, your `last_word()` can be written as follows for mutable strings (the arguments to `main()` being mutable):

```
void last_word (char *str)
{
    char *p = NULL,     /* your last */
        *ep = NULL;     /* end pointer to end of last */
    int in = 0;         /* flag - in/out of a word */

    while (*str) {                  /* loop over each char */
        if (my_isspace (*str)) {    /* if a space */
            if (in)                 /* if in a word */
                ep = str;           /* set endptr to current char */
            in = 0;                 /* set out of word */
        }
        else {                      /* not a space */
            if (!in)                /* if not in a word */
                p = str;            /* set start pointer */
            in = 1;                 /* set in word */
        }
        str++;          /* increment pointer */
    }

    if (p) {            /* if we have start of word */
        if (ep)         /* if we have endptr set */
            *ep = 0;    /* nul-terminate at endptr */
        my_putstr (p);  /* output last */
    }
}
```

(**note:** if dealing with non-mutable string input, you could use `ep - p` to get the number of characters to output and output them one at a time)

A complete example (with a few cleanups) could be:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int my_isspace (const char c)
{
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n' || c == '\r')
        return 1;

    return 0;
}

void my_putstr (const char *str)
{
    size_t n = 0;

    for (n = 0; str[n]; n++) {}

    write (1, str, n);
}

void last_word (char *str)
{
    char *p = NULL,     /* your last */
        *ep = NULL;     /* end pointer to end of last */
    int in = 0;         /* flag - in/out of a word */

    while (*str) {                  /* loop over each char */
        if (my_isspace (*str)) {    /* if a space */
            if (in)                 /* if in a word */
                ep = str;           /* set endptr to current char */
            in = 0;                 /* set out of word */
        }
        else {                      /* not a space */
            if (!in)                /* if not in a word */
                p = str;            /* set start pointer */
            in = 1;                 /* set in word */
        }
        str++;          /* increment pointer */
    }

    if (p) {            /* if we have start of word */
        if (ep)         /* if we have endptr set */
            *ep = 0;    /* nul-terminate at endptr */
        my_putstr (p);  /* output last */
    }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    my_putstr ("'");
    if (argc >= 2)
        last_word (argv[1]);
    my_putstr ("'");
    my_putstr ("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Single word:

```
$ ./bin/write_last_argv1 "fleas"
'fleas'
```

Single word with trailing whitespace:

```
$ ./bin/write_last_argv1 "fleas      "
'fleas'
```

Multiple words:

```
$ ./bin/write_last_argv1 "my dog has fleas"
'fleas'
```

Multiple words with leading, trailing and multiple intervening whitespace:

```
$ ./bin/write_last_argv1 "  my    dog  has fleas   "
'fleas'
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Good point in considering the other possible spaces. Also, `\f` and `\v` will be considered as a space in addition to the function. Talking with my peers also mentioned to do your method (have a starting pointer with the end pointer to find the last word of the string), but I wasn't really sure how to properly implement it. Your comments make it more readable and good understanding it. Thanks for lea

Comment: On top of my `last_word` problem, someone mentioned that I'm not checking for the `my_isspace` condition when it comes printing. So, I added an extra condition for my while loop in `my_putstr` to `(*str && (!(my_isspace(*str))))` and seems working fine too :)

Comment: Yes, that is good practice and a required check `(*str && ...)` to ensure you are not attempting to categorize the *nul-character*. Also, since you are not assigning the result, there are no additional sets of parens, e.g. `(!(..))` needed. `(*str && !my_isspace (*str))` is fine.